# Preventing AJAX call from timing out

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

One of my websites needs to call the API of another one of my websites.

My plan to display a "wait" popup while the page makes an AJAX call to direct the server-side code to make the API call.

But there is the potential that it could take a little while. I'm looking for advice on how to prevent the AJAX call from timing out.

When I Google this issue, most of the articles I've read suggest sending just a few items at a time. But in my case, it's all done in one rather substantial call.

What other options are there to prevent the page from timing out?

Comment: Did you try the timeout parameter? You can specify the timeout, like `timeout: 3000 ` for timeout of 3 seconds

Comment: @PM.: I didn't but wondered about that. That might be a nice fallback approach if there's no way to set up some sort of "pings" while the server is busy.

Comment: Do you mean that, you would like to check if server is busy before making your ajax call, and if it is busy, show your wait popup, if not then make your ajax call?

Comment: @PM.: No, I just wondered if there was some way to periodically ping the server somehow while it's making the API call. In other words, to find some way to have a back-and-forth communication while the work is being done, similar to how I might if I was sending just a few items at a time.

Comment: To keep connection alive, you can call some trivial API in some particular interval, but sending few items in same request would be difficult and clearly not a good solution. You can have separate call for those specific tasks, and keep the one call for pinging server time to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cant implement loading in packets etc, then timeout is probably your best option.

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: uriTrackers, // Your URL here.
        //data: data,  //we are not sending data, this is a different data to the one below
        timeout: 10000 //10 second timeout  or maybe 30 secs if debugging
    })
            .done(function (data) {
    // Anything you want to do on success here.
            })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
            $('#TrackerInfo').text('Error: ' + err + uriTrackers);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, I got that your need to keep server pinging in some particular time interval.

```
setInterval(function() {
  $.ajax({url: "ping.txt", 
          success: function(result){
                       //Nothing to do, or your can check the content of your ping.txt
                    },
          error : function(){
                               //Code to show your wait popup
                 }
          });
}, 60000);
```

This will keep your connection alive i.e. you would know if you are connected to the server.

You  need to put ping.txt on your server accordingly.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure this addresses the need. I assume the server will still be there and can be pinged no matter what. The problem here is that the AJAX call to do the actual work could time out, and I don't see how this would change that.

Comment: Oh OK then I guess timeout parameter would solve the issue.